# Read and overwrite data at each click of an actionButton

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app that reads a data frame and at every press of an actionButton returns the value of a specific column, one row at a time until all rows of the data frame have been read. The structure of the dataset is 3 columns, one for IDs, one for a characteristic and an indicator variable for the already read IDs (0/1). Every time the user presses the actionButton, the app reads one row of the dataset, starting from row 1, returns the value of a second variable in that row and changes the value of the third variable to 1. The tricky part for me is that I want to save the "used" ids, in order to continue the reading from the last used id after restarting the app. I have tried loading and saving the data at every step and using reactiveValues, but this does not seem to work well for me - probably I don't know how to use them correctly. I am very new in shiny, so any feedback is more than welcome.
An example of the code I have been using:

```
project.path <- getwd()
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1:20), gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 20, replace = TRUE), used = 0)
write.csv2(dat, file.path(project.path, "data.csv"), row.names = F)

saveData <- function(x) {
  write.csv2(x, file = file.path(project.path, "data.csv"), 
             row.names = FALSE)
}

loadData <- function() {
  dat <- read.csv2(file.path(project.path, "data.csv"))
  return(dat)
}


# UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Tittle"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("counter", "Start")
      ),
      
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("result")
                )
    )
  )

# SERVER
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  last <- reactive({
    d <- loadData()
    last <- min(d$id[d$used == 0]) -1
  })

  cur <- reactive({
    if(last() == 0){
      cur <- input$counter
    }else{
      cur <- last() + input$counter
    }
  })
  
  # Calculate Result
  ResultText <- reactive({
    d <-loadData()
    if (input$counter == 0 & last() == 0){
      paste0("No IDs have been used. Press button to start.")
    }else{
      if(input$counter > 0 & last() == 0){
        d$used[cur()] <- 1
        paste0("ID ", cur(), " is a  ", as.character(d$gender[cur()]))
      }else{
        if(input$counter == 0 & last() > 0){
          paste0("The last ID was ", d$id[last()], " (", as.character(d$gender[last()]), ") Press the button to continue reading the list.")
        }else{
          d$used[cur()] <- 1
          paste0("ID ", cur(), " is a ", as.character(d$gender[cur()]))
        }  
      }
    }
  })
  
  
  output$result <- renderText({
    ResultText()
  })
  
  observe({
    d <- loadData()
    if (input$counter > 0 & last() == 0){
      cur <- input$counter
      d$used[cur] <- 1
      saveData(d)
    }else{
      if(input$counter > 0 & last() > 0){
        d$used[cur()] <- 1
        saveData(d)
        
      }
    }
  }) 
}

# Run
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why not use numericInput, and get nth row from data?

Comment: because the purpose of the app is to go though the whole dataset sequentially and not just select specific rows

Comment: @acts I just tried out your code, and it seems to work. After pressing the button 5 times, the output file has 1 for the first 5 rows of `used` column...and when I quit and restarted it picked up again at same point...was something else expected? Or could you comment further about what isn't working for you?

Comment: @Ben, thanks a lot for the comment. For me, in the dataset the column used is indeed saved correctly, but when the app stops and re-starts, it starts again from the begining of the dataset.

Comment: @acts Hmmm...are you rewriting the data file again with zeroes accidentally by chance when you rerun it? I didn't have that problem when I quit the app and reran (making sure to avoid rewriting the data file again)...

Comment: yeap. Just commenting the write.csv line did the trick. Thanks a lot and sorry for waisting your time.

Comment: @acts No problem at all - glad it worked!